# Why is Oka's coherence theorem a deep result?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

This is a very naive question.

Let $X$ be a complex manifold. Let $\mathcal{O}_X$ be the structure sheaf of $X$, a sheaf of rings whose sections over opens $U\subset X$ are just the holomorphic functions $U\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$.

A sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules $F$ is coherent if:

1. It is locally finitely generated: Ie, there is an open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $X$ such that $F|_{U_i}$ admits surjections $\mathcal{O}_{U_i}\rightarrow F|_{U_i}$ for each $i$.
2. For any open $V\subset X$, and any morphism $f : \mathcal{O}_V^s\rightarrow F|_V$, $\text{Ker}(f)$ is a locally finitely generated sheaf on $V$ (ie, satisfies condition 1).

Then, Oka's coherence theorem states that the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ is coherent.

When $X$ is a scheme, this statement is almost tautological. What is it about the setting of complex manifolds that makes this theorem deep?

Comment: On a scheme, you need that the structure sheaf be locally Noetherian or something for the sheaf to be coherent, no?

Comment: On a scheme, the structure sheaf is coherent when it is, well, coherent. Coherence is strictly weaker than local noetherianness.

Comment: Well, sure. But apart from that tautological condition, you need, in real life, *something*.

Comment: Everything is deeper and harder for complex analytic spaces. What makes you think this should be any different?

Comment: Coherence of $\mathcal{O}_X$ is a nontrivial finiteness condition, even for schemes.  Does Georges Elencwajg's answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/129390/121 help at all?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In scheme theory applied to complex geometry one usually does not encounter coherent rings which are not noetherian as well.
However if $X$ is (for example) a Stein manifold then the ring $R = \mathcal{O}(X)$ of global holomorphic functions is typically non-noetherian, which makes remarkable the fact that $R$ is nonetheless coherent.

Comment: Since the question posed comes at the start of the complex-analytic theory, whereas Stein spaces lie much further into the theory, perhaps it is better to just try to prove coherence of $\mathscr{O}_{\mathbf{C}^2}$ by hand and then read the proof of Oka's theorem (such as in the book *Coherent Analytic Sheaves*) to sense the depth. It is somehow because complex manifolds are not built out of rings as schemes are that coherence properties of their sheaf theory are much more difficult; e.g., the analogous coherence theorem in rigid-analytic geometry isn't quite as deep.

Comment: Ah, I was recalling Hartshorne's definition of coherent as just a finitely generated quasi-coherent (so structure sheaves would be tautologically coherent), but forgot that he assumes all his schemes to be noetherian.

Comment: @oxeimon: there isn't even a very robust notion of "quasi-coherence" in the analytic setting (one can make a definition and prove some reasonable properties, but it lacks others one would want for a fully satisfactory notion). You gave the correct general definition of coherence in the question posed, due to Serre (motivated by experience in the complex-analytic case with Oka's work!); it does not require any notion of "quasi-coherence".